# access 2010 - parameters button is disabled

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

does anyone know why this is happening in access 2010 and not in 2007?

[image]

the parameters button is disabled and im not able to get into it at all. does anyone know how to get into the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since you're using an Access Data Project (Shippin_FE: **Project** - Shipping (Access 2002-2003 file form...) this means you're trying to add parameters to a SQL Server View.

That wouldn't work ever. You're confusing the SQL Server View editor and the Access Query editor. You can verify that its a View by selecting View -> SQL View. You'll see `ALTER VIEW` at the top

If you need to create something that accepts parameters you need to create a stored procedure instead.

Comment: i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

or a dynamic SQL statement.

you can use parameters mixed into SQL statements JUST LIKE you can with linked tables.

use this statement and tell me what happens

Select * From Employees Where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID

Better yet, you can do this

Select * From Employees Where EmployeeID = @txtFindEmployeeID

note, Access automatically binds between parameters and fields on your form.